# Convexity of $F$ and quadratic growth rate implies linear rate of $F'$

Tags: partial-differential-equations, convex-analysis

Let $F:\mathbb{R}^n\longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be convex such that
$$ |F(x)|\leq A|x|^2+B$$
for $A,B>0$. How can I deduce that,
$$ |DF(x)| \leq C(1+|x|)?$$

This fact was used multiple times in Evans book "Weak convergence method for nonlinear PDEs", but I don't know why?

Answer (score 1):

Also, using a quite big theorem of convex functions (refer to "Measure Theories and Fine Properties of Functions", L.C.Evans) Page 267, Theorem 6.7

where he proved that a function $f:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is convex then there exists a contant C only depending on n such that $$
\underset { B \left( x , \frac { r } { 2 } \right) }{\mathtt{ess.sup}} | D f | \leq \frac { C } { r } \dfrac{1}{|B_r|}\int _ { B ( x , r ) } | f | d y.
$$
This provides us the result rigourously.

Comment: The book that I have only have the last page is 257, could you send me a link for the one you used?

Comment: I found it, thanks!

Comment: Sorry for the type error, the book I mentioned above is the revised version and published in 2015. I believe you will find it on [link](http://libgen.io)

Answer (score 0):

Argue by contradiction, suppose that there exists suitable $\{x_k\}_{k=1}^{\infty}$ such that $$|DF(x_k)|>k(1+|x_k|).$$

For $k\gg 2A+100B,$ after a rotation, and note that by the convexity $D^2F\geq 0$ we can assume with out loss of generality that  $\partial_1F(x_k+cI)\geq \partial_1F(x_k)=|DF(x_k)|\geq k(1+|x_k|),\ \ \forall c\geq 0$. Hence  we " integral on this line" will provide us a contradiction to the growth condition of $|F|\leq A|x|+B$.

This may not be a rigorous proof, but it seems enough to make sure this result holds. Hoping for a more rigorous proof come up. Best Regards!